# How to use regular expressions to return only a part of a file name?

Tags: regex, sed, grep, expression

I am having trouble to create a regular expression that returns only a part of a string.

Passing the following strings:

```
/path/of/the/file/1 - 2 - Lecture 1.2_ Max Bense (13_49).mp4
/path/of/the/file/1 - 3 - Lecture 1.3_ Michael Friedman (12_15).mp4
/path/of/the/file/2 - 1 - Lecture 2.1_ Paul Feyerabend (12_55).mp4
/path/of/the/file/2 - 2 - Lecture 2.2_ Alhazen (11_37).mp4
/path/of/the/file/3 - 2 - Lecture 3.2_ Study Case - Dominicus Gundissalinus (14_30).mp4 
/path/of/the/file/3 - 3 - Lecture 3.3_ Study Case - Carl Friedrich von Weizsacker (11_48).mp4
```

It should return only the following parts respectively:

```
Max Bense
Michael Friedman
Paul Feyerabend
Alhazen
Study Case - Dominicus Gundissalinus
Study Case - Carl Friedrich von Weizsacker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use PCRE and Positive Lookbehind

If you have access to a regular expression engine that supports PCRE expressions, you can use positive lookbehind to get just the text you want from your MP3 listings. For example:

```
pcregrep -o '(?<=_ )([^(]+)' /tmp/foo
```

#### Use Sed

If you don't have a Perl-compatible grep, then you can use sed instead. It's a lot less readable, but a lot more portable. For example:

```
sed 's/.*_ \([^(]\+\).*/\1/' /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems an easy job for `awk`. It splits the line in fields with chars `_` or `(`, so the name will be the second one, and then removes leading and trailing spaces for that field:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        FS = "[_(]" ;
    } 
    { 
        gsub( /^ *| *$/, "", $2 ); 
        print $2 ;
    }
' infile
```

Output:

```
Max Bense
Michael Friedman
Paul Feyerabend
Alhazen
Study Case - Dominicus Gundissalinus
Study Case - Carl Friedrich von Weizsacker
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript solution:

```
var files=["/path/of/the/file/1 - 2 - Lecture 1.2_ Max Bense (13_49).mp4",
"/path/of/the/file/1 - 3 - Lecture 1.3_ Michael Friedman (12_15).mp4",
"/path/of/the/file/2 - 1 - Lecture 2.1_ Paul Feyerabend (12_55).mp4",
"/path/of/the/file/2 - 2 - Lecture 2.2_ Alhazen (11_37).mp4",
"/path/of/the/file/3 - 2 - Lecture 3.2_ Study Case - Dominicus Gundissalinus (14_30).mp4",
"/path/of/the/file/3 - 3 - Lecture 3.3_ Study Case - Carl Friedrich von Weizsacker (11_48).mp4​​​​"];
var regex=/_\s(.+)\s/;

​for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(regex.exec(files[i])[1]);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8zPv/